# Angular directives work only in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying create a directive, that will create a nested form, where basic rule is one of option  call function, that get a option to next field. Everything is all right in firefox, but in chrome and IE functions binded with scope(showPackages,showOptions)  not working - like ng-click is not fired when i select first options .
Spotted You  with this issue?

```
define( ['angular',
         'ngRoute', 
         'ngResource',
         'AssetsModule'
       ], function(angular, 
                   ngRoute, 
                   ngResource,
                   AssetsModule                   
         ){

            return angular.module('ContentComparision', ['ngRoute', 'AssetsModule'])
                  .controller('navController', ['$scope', 'AssetsModuleFactory',   function( $scope, AssetsModuleFactory ){


                          $scope.nav = {};


                          AssetsModuleFactory.getDistinictGroups( 
                              function(data){           
                                      $scope.nav.origins = data;
                              }
                          );

                          $scope.showPackages = 
                              function(origin){

                                  AssetsModuleFactory.getPackagesByOrigin(
                                         origin, 
                                         function(data){      

                                                 $scope.nav.packages = data;
                                                 $scope.nav.addoptions = [];  
                                         }
                                  );                           
                           };                  

                          $scope.showOptions = 
                              function(id){
                                  if ( typeof ( id ) === 'undefined' ) id = 0;

                                  AssetsModuleFactory.getAddonalOptionsById(
                                         id, 
                                         function(data){       

                                                 $scope.nav.addoptions = data;
                                         }
                                  );                           
                         };  


                  }])
                  .directive('appNav', function(){
                    return{
                      restrict: 'AEC',
                      templateUrl: 'views/beforeAssets.html?cache=false',

                      link: function($scope, el, attr) {    

                      } 
                    };
                  })                  

                      ;
        });
```

AsstesModule.js:

(function ( define, angular ){

```
'use strict';

define([
        'angular',
        'ngRoute'
      ],
      function ( angular ){


        /*   Asset Module
         *  
         */
         angular.module('AssetsModule', ['ngRoute'])
                      .factory('AssetsModuleFactory', function($http){


                          /**
                           * valueInArr - helper function
                           * @param {String|Int} value
                           * @param {array} arr
                           */
                          var valueInArr = function(value, arr){
                            for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                               if( value === arr[i]) return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                          }

                          return {
                          /**
                           * Rest Service Path
                           */                                
                            address: 'js/REST/nav.json',

                            /**
                             * Get Groups - connect with service and return all groups of origin
                             * @param {function} success callback function when get request is done
                             * @param {function} error callback function when get request is done, but broken
                             * @returns {void}
                             */
                            'getDistinictGroups': function(success, error){

                             // TODO: Cache 
                             // TODO: Handlers on-demand 
                              $http.get(this.address)
                                    .success(function(data){
                                        var unique = [];

                                        for( var i in data){
                                           if ( !valueInArr ( data[i].origin, unique) ) unique.push( data[i].origin );
                                        }

                                        success( unique );
                                    })
                                    .error(function(data){
                                      error();
                                    });

                             },

                             /**
                             * Get Groups - connect with service and return all groups of origin
                             * @param {function} success callback function when get request is done
                             * @param {function} error callback function when get request is done, but broken
                             * @returns {void}
                             */
                            'getPackagesByOrigin': function(origin, success, error){

                             // TODO: Cache 
                              $http.get(this.address)
                                    .success(function(data){
                                        var packages = [];

                                        for( var i in data){
                                           if ( data[i].origin === origin ) packages.push( data[i] );
                                        }

                                        success( packages );
                                    })
                                    .error(function(data){
                                      error();  
                                    });

                             },

                             /**
                             * Get Groups - connect with service and return all groups of origin
                             * @param {int} id  of Package 
                             * @param {function} success callback function when get request is done
                             * @param {function} error callback function when get request is done, but broken
                             * @returns {void}
                             */
                            'getAddonalOptionsById': function(id, success, error){

                             // TODO: Cache 
                              $http.get(this.address)
                                    .success(function(data){

                                        for( var i in data){
                                           if ( data[i].id === id ){
                                             success ( data[i].addonalOptions );
                                             return;
                                           }
                                        }
                                        success ( [ ] );

                                    })
                                    .error(function(data){
                                      error();
                                    });

                             }



                          };
                      });


      }

);
```

})(define, angular);

beforeAssets.html

```
<div>    
    <select class="form-control" >
        <option ng-repeat="p in nav.origins" ng-click="showPackages(  p  );  " >  {{ p }}</option>    
    </select>

    <select class="form-control" >
        <option ng-repeat="p in nav.packages track by $index" ng-click="$parent.showOptions( p.id )">{{p.name}}</option>    
    </select>

   <!-- Additional Options -->
   <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="o in nav.addoptions track by $index" >
    <label >
      <input type="checkbox" /> {{o}}
    </label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: how about checking the console and making a jsfiddle/plnkr?

Comment: Console don't return any error. It is weird for my, because in firefox all working. I dont create jsfiddle since i use requirejs and can't exclude is origin of problem.

Comment: I find a reason - it is a <select> and ng-click couple - in chrome and IE is not work well. Somebody meet with this?